# ¿Obtener datos por AJAX con el método GET?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando cambiar el contenido de un modal con el AJAX por GET, el problema es que al hacer la petición me da como resultado todo el html de la pagina y no entiendo porque.
Este es el código de AJAX que uso,

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/segundapuesta.shop/producto/vista&id=5', true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = acciones;

    function acciones(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
```

Al parecer funciona de alguna manera, pero me da como resultado lo siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No se porque me da esos datos, cuando en realidad lo estoy mandando a un archivo php con una funcion especifica.

Comment: Seguramente no estás analizando si la petición es AJAX o "normal" y estás creando la página completa en lugar de devolver solo el elemento especificado.

Comment: Los archivos que procesan las peticiones Ajax deben ser pensados como **archivos auxiliares**, que se dediquen solamente a recibir los datos, a procesarlos y a devolver la respuesta esperada por el cliente. Si en ese archivo auxiliar tú pones etiquetas html, imprimes cosas varias, etc... todo volverá al cliente cuando dirijas la petición a ese archivo. Eso es lo que está pasando en este caso. Cambia tu archivo para que saque por pantalla solamente lo que necesitas.